# Is there any way to override Angular datalist autocompletion behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-datalist

I have a basic implementation of datalist where the options are being dynamically generated from a database search as the user is typing.  However, some of the suggestions do not contain the query string within their selection value as the query matches with a field within its document body.

Ex: User types in 'ap'; the list of suggestions passed to the datalist options might be [ 'apple', 'fruit salad' ] as 'fruit salad' may contain 'apple' in a child field.  However, 'fruit salad' would not be visible as an option to the user as its phrase does not contain the query string 'ap'.

Is there any way to override this default behaviour?  If not, what might be a quick alternative (or is it just best to define a custom directive for it)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumuing that your filtering a data list via ng-model=[MODEL] and |filter:[MODEL].  If that's not the case, then I'm totally off.

This would have to be fixed in the data that you're returning.  Include another field with keywords or a category.

i.e.

```
[
{displayvalue:"Fruit Salad",keywords:"apple, health food,yummy yummy"},
{displayvalue:"Mashed Potatoes",keywords:"starch, side dish"}
]
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific in my question about this.  I'm filtering the datalist options completely independently of angular (i.e. it takes place as a process in the back-end), and the database is too big and has too many possible related keywords in order to make this process feasible.  Thanks for the response, however!